# Where exactly do these supposed images of structures on the Moon and other bodies come from?

Tags: the-moon

I'm sure you have seen these kind of images before, and the gullible people who think they are real, some just look stupid and obviously fake, others look kind of convincing. Even though they obviously aren't

I'm wondering if anyone knows how these get made, and who makes them, are they doing it to trick the gullible people or something else? Like crop circles.

Comment: Can you give any examples of what you're talking about?

Comment: Some examples 1. https://www.express.co.uk/news/science/623085/PICTURED-Does-this-picture-prove-aliens-in-a-UFO-watched-the-Moon-landings  2. http://ufosightingshotspot.blogspot.com/2016/10/alien-missile-or-ufo-caught-next-to-moon.html  3. https://nationalufocenter.com/2014/08/google-earth-map-spots-alien-like-figure-moon/

Comment: @Heopps great comment! Those last two links are wonderful examples of pareidolia.

Answer (score 6):

> Pareidolia (/pærɪˈdoʊliə/ parr-i-DOH-lee-ə) is a psychological
>   phenomenon in which the mind responds to a stimulus, usually an image
>   or a sound, by perceiving a familiar pattern where none exists.

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia)

If one is predisposed to expect certain things, you can pore over a blurry image until you convince yourself you are seeing what you are looking for.

The Wikipedia article shows the Face as an example

[image]

Comment: Only that the Face is on Mars, but the rest ist correct. And sometimes media goes miles to get mote clicks i.e.) blue dune on Mars.. In false colour, ok for scientific purposes but definitely not enough for a sensation.